# Flutter Windows App: Error when getting thumbnails from C++ dll using ffi

Tags: c++, windows, flutter, ffi

-- Edit

I have found that the code works fine when running within my flutter app, however it doesn't work when being run from a test case.  Is there any reason why this would be any different?

--Original Question

I would like to be able to get file thumbnail images that I can use in my flutter app on windows only. So I have:

- Created a C++ library project (VS 2019 community) that gets the thumbnail from an image (and saves it to disk as a test).
- Created a C++ test project that calls the function in the dll and successfully returns the thumbnail.
- Configured my flutter app to use the DLL using ffi.

However, although the C++ test works, when I call the function from flutter it fails when calling the dll and returns an error at the line :

```
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(buf, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psi));
```

with an HResult of 2147942487 (which I think is can't find the file)

Could anyone give me any help as to why this might be happening?   Does the ffi layer add any additional security that might be stopping the file access from working through flutter?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

This is the C++ code:

```
struct Array
{
    int* array;
    int len;
    HRESULT result; 

};
wchar_t* convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
{
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}

Array* GetThumbnailB() {
    Array* a = new Array();
    const char* charval = "full path to image here";
    wchar_t* buf = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(charval);
    
    std::vector<BYTE> data;

    ULONG_PTR token;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput tmp;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token, &tmp, NULL);

    IShellItemImageFactory* psi;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(buf, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psi));
    HBITMAP image;

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        SIZE size;
        size.cx = 100;
        size.cy = 100;

        hr = psi->GetImage(size, SIIGBF_SCALEUP, (&image));

        //save as png
        if (save_png_memory(image, data))
        {
            //write from memory to file for testing:
            std::ofstream fout("test.png", std::ios::binary);
            fout.write((char*)data.data(), data.size());
            int* rtn;
            rtn = (int*)malloc(data.size());
            memcpy(&rtn[0], data.data(), data.size());
            a->array = rtn;
            a->len = data.size();
            a->result = 1;
        }
        else {
            a->result = 3;
            a->len = 3;
        }
        DeleteObject(image);
    }
    else {
        a->result = hr;
        a->len = 2; 
    }
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(token);
    
    return a;
}
```

This is the flutter code:

```
typedef GetTNNative = Pointer<Array> Function();
typedef GetTNFlutter = Pointer<Array> Function();

 void GetThumbnail() {
    final path64 =
        r'<path to the dll>';
    final dylib = DynamicLibrary.open(path64);
    final getThumbnail=
        dylib.lookupFunction<GetTNNative, GetTNFlutter>("GetThumbnailB");
  var rtn = getThumbnail();
```